# Multiprocessing vs Concurrent.futures library python (not working on Google Compute Engine)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing, google-compute-engine, concurrent.futures

I am trying to parallelize a pandas operation which splits a dataframe column having comma separated values into 2 columns. Normal pandas operation is taking around 5 secs on my python instance which directly uses `df.str.split` on that particular column. My dataframe contains 2 million rows and hence I'm trying to bring down the code running time.

As the first approach to parallelize, I am using Python's multiprocessing library by creating pools equivalent to number of CPU cores available on my instance. For the second approach to the same problem, I am using `concurrent.futures` library by mentioning a `chunksize` of 4.
However, I see that multiprocessing library is taking around the same time as the normal pandas operation(5 secs) whereas the `concurrent.futures` is taking more than a minute to run the same line.

1) Does a Google Compute Engine support these Python multiprocessing libraries?
2) Why is the parallel processing not working on the GCP?

Thanks in advance. Below is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

def split(e):
    return e.split(",")

df =  pd.DataFrame({'XYZ':['CAT,DOG', 
      'CAT,DOG','CAT,DOG']})

pool = Pool(4)
df_new = pd.DataFrame(pool.map(split, df['XYZ'], columns = ['a','b'])
df_new = pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=1)
```

The above code is taking about the same time as the code below which is a normal pandas operation which uses only one core:

```
df['a'], df['b'] = df['XYZ'].str.split(',',1).str
```

Uisng concurrent.futures:

```
import concurrent.futures
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
     a = pd.DataFrame(pool.map(split, df['XYZ'], chunksize = 4), 
     columns=['a','b'])
print (a)
```

The above code using concurrent.futures is taking more than a minute to run on the GCP. Please note that the code I have posted is just the sample code. The dataframe I am using in the project have 2 million such rows. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Hi , which product we are talking about it? Remember that GCP is a platform with a bunch of products inside ( GCE, GKE DataProc). Could you be more specific about it?

Comment: Its a GCE with 4 cpus.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why did you choose `chunksize=4`? This is pretty small, for 2 million rows this would only break it into 500,000 operations. The total runtime might only take 1/4th of the time, but the additional overhead would likely make this take longer than a single-threaded approach.

I'd recommend using a much larger `chunksize`. Anywhere from 10,000 to 200,000 might be appropriate, but you should tweak this based on some experimentation with the results you get.

Comment: Hey Dustin, thanks for the suggestion. The results are better when I increase the chunksize to around 200,000. However, after the experimentation with different values, the best time i could get was around 6 secs. I assume this is because of the overhead of the subprocesses involved in the parallelization. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Six seconds sounds pretty reasonable for 2M rows to me. I think the operation is simple enough here that making it concurrent might not be improving anything.